# why I cannot run bzr explorer

Tags: python, macos, bazaar, bzr-svn

I have python as seen in

```
which python
```

and also

```
➜  ~  brew install qt
Warning: qt-4.8.6 already installed
➜  ~  brew install pyqt
Warning: pyqt-4.10.4 already installed
```

but then I try to run on my OSX:

```
➜  ~  bzr explorer
```

and gets this error:

```
invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
    Unable to load u'bzr-explorer' in u'/Users/me/.bazaar/plugins' as a plugin because the file path isn't a valid module name; try renaming it to u'explorer'.
    bzr: ERROR: No module named PyQt4
    You may need to install this Python library separately.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your Bazaar Explorer plugin is installed in `/Users/me/.bazaar/plugins/bzr-explorer`. Rename that directory to `/Users/me/.bazaar/plugins/explorer` and then it should work. (As the error message was trying to tell you.)

Btw, I recommend using the `dmg` file from the official website (http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/MacOSXDownloads). Bazaar Explorer is included in it and should work out of the box.