# Can't run `bzr explorer` on Mac OS 10.9.x

Tags: macos, pyqt4, bazaar

Unfortunately, the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24981688/why-i-cannot-run-bzr-explorer) did not answer my problem. :(

I have the following installed:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05)

$ brew install qt
Warning: qt-4.8.6 already installed

$ brew install pyqt
Warning: pyqt-4.11.1 already installed

$ brew install sip
Warning: sip-4.16.3 already installed
```

Then when I try to run `bzr explorer`, it returns the following:

```
$ bzr explorer
bzr: ERROR: No module named PyQt4
You may need to install this Python library separately.
```

I am running on Mac OS 10.9.x.
My `/Users/me/.bazaar/plugins` directory have the following:

```
$ ll
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  25 me  staff  850 Oct  9 15:21 explorer
drwxr-xr-x  20 me  staff  680 Oct  9 15:22 qbzr
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If you run `python` and then `import PyQt4` what does it say?

Comment: @JohnZwinck, I get the following >>> import PyQt4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named PyQt4

Comment: Then it seems like the problem is PyQt4 is not installed, or not installed properly.  Maybe you can use the "brew" tool to list what files are owned by the pyqt package you have installed...either they are simply not in  your $PYTHONPATH or it's the wrong package, or something.

Comment: @JohnZwinck, I managed to resolve this error: `bzr: ERROR: No module named PyQt4` but now when I try to run the command `bzr explorer` I get a new error `bzr: ERROR: No module named sip`. The procedure I did to resolve the PyQt4 error could not resolve this one. ;(

Comment: PyQt4 was missing its symlink inside `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`. I tried doing the same to sip but didn't work.

Comment: Well it sounds like you're on the right track at least--by the way you didn't have to make a symlink (but it's OK that you did)...you could just set the $PYTHONPATH environment variable to include the directory where `brew` is putting its packages...then it will work for all packages and you won't need a symlink when you install new ones.  By the way, if you're using the system default Python, you might consider using `brew` to install a different (newer) one and see if that changes things.